# How do I write a function that returns true if there are duplicate words in a file

Tags: python, string, file, duplicates

Here's the function

```
def duplicate(fname):
    'returns true if there are duplicates in the file, false otherwise'
    fn = open(fname, 'r')
    llst = fn.readlines()
    fn.close()
```

I have no idea where go with this. I tried splitting the file, sorting it, and then writing a function to find whether or not two identical words are in consecutive order. But it said I can't attribute split to the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be clearer about your specification - an example of an input that should `return True` and one that should `return False` would be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I'll note that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) data structure for this:

```
def has_duplicate_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words = set()
        for line in f.readlines():
            lineWords = line.split()
            for word in lineWords:
                if word in words:
                    return True

                words.add(word)
    return False
```

Note also that this depends on your definition of what a *word* is. In this solution it's any sequence of characters not containing whitespace characters, i.e. space, tab, newline, return, formfeed as defined in `split()` function [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

If you want to return all duplicates you can accumulate them in a `list` instead of doing `return True` when a duplicate is found.

Also note that this solution is not feasible if it is possible for the file to contain extremely long lines that won't fit into memory.

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't understand how set works.

Answer (score 1):

You could add each word to a dictionary as a key. If the key already exist, it's a duplicate. You can also associate a count of the number of times a word was found as the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def duplicate(fname):
    'returns true if there are duplicates in the file, false otherwise'
    with open (fname, 'r') as file_handle:
        word_dict = dict()
        for line in file_handle:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                if word in word_dict:
                    word_dict[word] = 'Duplicate'
                else:
                    word_dict[word] = 'Unique'
    return word_dict

results = duplicate('alice.txt')
for key in results:
    print "{}: {}".format(key, results[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for this?

```
def duplicate(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f: # it's better to use with open, than only open, since otherwise the file might not be closed on error
        dict = {} # create an empty dictionary for checking, if a line was already in the file
        for line in f: # go through all lines
            try:
                foo = dict[line] # check, if line already exists
                return True # no error was thrown, so this is a duplicated line
            except:
                dict[line] = 1 # give the key line some random input, so that the dict contains this key
    return False
```

Another way of doing this would be by reading in this file, sorting the lines, and then check for douplicate lines, that then would follow each other.

Please note, if the file contains the lines "foo" and "foo " this will not return true but false, because of the space at the end of the second line.

Comment: `dict` doesn't make sense here. You should use `set` instead.

Comment: well, in python dicts are as fast as sets, so why not?

Comment: Well, you could also implement a `dict` yourself to be as fast as the built-in. You could also think of 10 other equally "fast" (whatever you mean) solutions here. But what for? Use the right tool for the job. `dict` here makes the code unreadable, putting some "random input" into the `dict` is pointless and confuses the readers (hence comments in your code are needed). `set` is the cleanest and simplest solution here.

Comment: nay, a self implemented dict in python would never be as fast as the build in dicts. Pythons dicts are written (and optimized) in C++ themself, so as long as you don't import C++ code these are always faster.

Comment: It's C actually (in the most popular Python implementation at least), and sure why not write it yourself. Anyway, great that you've attempted to tackle the most irrelevant part of my comment. Care to refer to the rest?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach: Compare the lengths of the list of words in the file with the length of a set of those words:

```
>>> def HasDuplicates(str):
...    words = str.split()
...    uniqueWords = set(words)
...    return len(words) != len(uniqueWords)
...
>>> str1 = "this is a sentence with two two duplicates"
>>> str2 = "this is a sentence with no duplicates"
>>> HasDuplicates(str1)
True
>>> HasDuplicates(str2)
False
```

(File I/O left as an exercise for the reader; it's not really germane to the issue of duplicates or not)

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

It returns `True` if there are duplicates, but also builds a dictionary with the duplicate words as `key` and their frequency in the text as the `value` and prints it. More than you asked for I know, but it wouldn't take much to change the code to just check for duplicates and return True/False.

```
def duplicate(fname):

    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read() # auto closes file after reading

    split_text = [word.strip() for word in text.split()] # create list of all the words

    duplicates = {}
    for word in split_text:
        count = text.count(word) # count occurrences of each word
        if count > 1:
            duplicates[word] = count
    if duplicates:
        print duplicates
        return True
    return False
```

**Example output:**

```
{'dear': 2, 'the': 6, 'name': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filepath','r') as f:
    all_words = f.read().split()
    return len(all_words) > len(set(all_words))
```

Comment: Why do you use the list comprehension there? The return value from the split() is already the exact same list that you're creating in the comprehension...

Comment: You're right! That was leftover from a different algorithm i was trying. Thanks!